# flash get function's argument name

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, function, arguments

I want to get all arguments names of a function inside the function

example:

```
function fct(var1:string,var2:string){
  var names:Array=...
  trace(names);
}
```

must trace : var1,var2

Thanks!

Comment: you can use describeType - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#describeType() - althought you may need to put fct function in a class first (maybe)

Comment: I don't think that function instances work like other Class instances.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, this is not possible. The closest you can get is the argument number and value. See below:

```
function fct( ... args ):void {
    for ( var v:Object in args ) {
        trace( v + ": " + args[v] );
    }
}
var str1:String = "this is a test";
var str2:String = "this is another test";
fct( str1, str2 );

//output
//0: this is a test
//1: this is another test
```

For future reference, you can use `...` + a variable name to allow for as many arguments as you need. Regardless, you should just need to access `args[ INDEX ]` rather than the actual variable name, which you wouldn't be able to access anyway because there would be no way to apply scope (such as `variableName[ "propertyName" ]`)

Comment: All loops are essentially the same. The only difference is how they run. `for each` is a shortcut to `for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){ var obj = a[i]}`, just incredibly slow. Each type of loop will produce the same result, it just uses different means to get that result.

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke. A for loop without the each will give names if names are to be had. But the names aren't there, just numbers.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible like native method, but you can use metadata tag to set arguments names. I create simple example. But i don't understand how it can help you in real projects:

```
[Arguments(param1="arg1",param2="arg2")]
public function test(arg1:Number, arg2:Number):void {

    var desc_xml:XML = describeType(Object(this).constructor);
    var metas_xml:XMLList = desc_xml.factory.method.(@name == "test");
    var args_xml:XMLList =   metas_xml.metadata.(@name == "Arguments");

    for each (var argx:XML in args_xml.arg)
    {
        trace(argx.@value.toXMLString());
    }

};
```

I use flex 4.6. Don't forget add each existing Metadata tags to the compiler argument with “-keep-as3-metadata+=Arguments”. It need for compile release versions.

Comment: I've never seen this method before. Neat trick. Either way, I agree this is entirely overkill for what the asker likely needs.

Comment: Absolutely true, but after questions i liked find opportunity solution